# After migrating WordPress website, got a new error when trying to view some images

Tags: wordpress, image, migration

I've just migrated a website live, and some images are coming up with a strange error:

"Error occured while calculating source (passed through env): No image roots defined in config."

Example URL: https://piktochart.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Template-09-Lead-gen-handbook.jpg

Anyone seen this before?

This is only happening on some of the images. I cannot find the cause, I've disabled/re-enabled caching.
I've downloaded the images from the server and they look fine.

Comment: Check your local .htaccess (or .conf Nginx) file if any plugin/custom edit is manipulating *.jpg files

Comment: I've done this, but unfortunately, it hasn't worked :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have faced this issue on my own site,I managed, as well.

You can use a plugin that manipulates images, such as WebP Express? Check your *htaccess* file for rewrite rules involve jpg or png files. I used the above plugin, but it was disabled and the *htaccess* rules were left in place; trying to redirect images to a page that it couldn’t handle.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately though it hasn't done the trick.

Comment: your htaccess file having any rewrite rules involve jpg or png files ?

Comment: There are no rewrite rules.

Comment: please check the link of your image, i just check and now its working.

Comment: if your problem has been solved, please don't forget to tick my answer as correct answer. @MichaelWeaver

Comment: It turns out the .htaccess file was cached by Cloudflare.

Comment: @MichaelWeaver, yes this type of error coming up by .htaccess file or cache problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was caused by Webp Express, the plugin also gave a notice: `It seems your server setup does not support headers in .htaccess. You should either fix this (install mod_headers) or deactivate the "Enable direct redirection to existing converted images?" option. Otherwise the Vary:Accept header will not be added and this can result in problems for users behind proxy servers (ie used in larger companies)`

Setting the Operation mode to "No conversion" solved my issue.